# Realtime logging and processing of massive data income

Tags: android, multithreading

My app is processing a massive data income and should be able to save the incoming data into a log file. Every `2ms` there comes a new message. This message has a `frameFormat`, a `frameType`, a `dataLength`, a `messageID` and, most important, the `data`.

I need to watch which `messageID` the message has, and process the `data`, which is an int array of 8 hex numbers.

On the one hand I need to show every single value of the int array in a graph. I'm using `Android GraphView Library`. It works well for the first 3k to 5k entries, then I get `ANR` dialog.

When I try to log the data part as `String` in a text file, the app gives immediately an `ANR`

Everything that is long-term-running runs in its own `Thread`

My question now is: Is the mass of data in general to much? Or do I even have to split the tasks within the `Threads` to its smallest parts?

Comment: You can probably keep up with the rate of data, but you are going to have to accept that you cannot make the updates in realtime.  Rather, catch all the data but accept that the updates will be in batches.  And yes, you will likely need to use proper threading.

Comment: so at the moment I have a Thread which is updating all different graphs every 2ms. So I should have for every graph a single update thread?